# Styling Placeholder Text in Contact Form 7

Tags: php, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

Is it possible to add html or styling of any kind within Contact Form 7 placeholder tags?

```
[text* text-name placeholder "Name"]
```

But would like to include some italicized font, so that there is some emphasis.
I tried

```
[text* text-name placeholder "name <em>please list your full name</em>"]
```

and

```
[text* text-name placeholder "Name <span>please provide your full name</span>"]
```

But the HTML displays instead of styling.

[image]

***Any thoughts?***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change a HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-a-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can, just get the element ID from the input (use chrome console and inspect the field), search for , after doing this go to apeareance of the theme in wordpress admin panel, and search for custom css section.

Go there and write this:

```
#something_here {
     font-style: italic;
}
```

Dont forget to put the right ID in "something_here"

Comment: That's for the CSS of the entire placeholder. I am trying to put code inside of the placeholder text, not the entire tag.

Comment: If you need all control to custom the form, I advice you to create a template in wordpress, call the header and footer function, and insert the form manually with phpmailer, then create a new page in wordpress panel and select the template created, doing this you will have full control and easy edit of your form.